# Wiremock gzip;deflate header ignored?

Tags: java, wiremock

I'm writing a simple unit test using Wiremock in order to test if my http client can disable gzip compression on demand.
The problem I'm facing is that it seems that wiremock is ignoring the Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate header.
Here is a simple test case:

```java
   @Test
    public void getContentWithGZIP() throws Exception {
        WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(wireMockConfig().port(8060));
        wireMockServer.start();
        wireMockServer.stubFor(post(urlEqualTo("/gzip-response")).willReturn(aResponse().withBody("body text")));

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8060/gzip-response");
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity("{payload:null}");
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
        logger.debug("response={}", EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity));
        Arrays.asList(response.getAllHeaders()).stream().forEach(header -> logger.debug(" header={} value={}", header.getName(), header.getValue()));
        Header contentEncodingHeader = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
        Assert.assertEquals("gzip", contentEncodingHeader.getValue());
    }
```

I'm using wiremock 2.5 and apache http client 4.4.1
Running the test with the apache client at the debug level I can see the data "on the wire".
I can see the request contains the Accepting-Encodging" header

```
16:01:23.283 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "POST /gzip-response HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
16:01:23.283 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Length: 14[\r][\n]"
16:01:23.283 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1[\r][\n]"
16:01:23.283 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: localhost:8060[\r][\n]"
16:01:23.283 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
16:01:23.283 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.4.1 (Java/1.8.0_212)[\r][\n]"
16:01:23.283 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
16:01:23.284 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
```

But the response is lacking the `Content-Encoding` one:

```
16:01:23.620 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
16:01:23.621 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
16:01:23.621 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Server: Jetty(9.2.13.v20150730)[\r][\n]"
16:01:23.621 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
16:01:23.621 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "9[\r][\n]"
```

Perhaps I'm missing the obvious, but I can't find what is. Can anyone tell me where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Thats because `HttpClient` does the decompression for you by default, and when it does that it removes these headers from the `Response` object.

Refer to this [Github link](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/4.5.x/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/client/protocol/ResponseContentEncoding.java#L123), where headers are being removed on line ResponseContentEncoding.java

This [Jmeter discussion thread](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59401%20http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/jmeter/trunk/src/protocol/http/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPHC4Impl.java?annotate=1742324&pathrev=1742324) gives history as to how another team handled the same scenario.

Comment: Well formatted answers get more attention on stackoverflow, see here https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for how to format your answers to make them stand out, specifically how to correctly add a link.

Comment: @KaiPi I'm not sure that you spot the cause, in my post I was logging the wire, not the response headers. You are right that the response headers are removed, but I think they should be logged on the wire